# MetaMaskでのネットワーク切り替え方法

Tags: ethereum

MetaMaskでRinkeby Test Networkへの切り替えを行いたいのですが、ネットワークの選択肢として表示されません。
初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが、切り替える方法をご教示いただきたいです。

すでに試したことは以下2点です。

- 設定のネットワークから選択できないか試しましたが、ネットワークの詳細が見られるだけで切替方法はわかりませんでした。
- ネットワークの追加も試みましたが、「この URL は現在 rinkeby ネットワークで使用しています。」とのメッセージが表示されて追加できませんでした。

ネットワークの切り替えさえできれば、Rinkeby以外のTest Networkでも構いません。
環境はWindowsでChromeから使用しています。

以上お手数ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。

そのmetamaskのページの「詳細」タブから 「show test networks」 をonにしたら表示されます.

[image: 詳細タブ]

[image: show test networks]